# rails 2, Will_paginate, undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

So I am running a rails 2.3.11 app, with bundler and I am having the darndest time getting will_paginate to work.  Its returning the following error:

undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:...

```
def show
     @category = Category.find_by_url_name(params[:id])
     @brands = @category.brands.find(:all, :order => "name")  
     @categories = Category.find(:all)
     @meta_title = "#{@category.name}"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do |wants|
              @brand = @brands.first   
              @products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6,  :conditions => ['brand_id = ? AND category_id = ?', @brand.id, @category.id])
      render :template => 'brands/show'
      end
      format.xml  { render :xml => @category }
    end
  end
```

this is my controller action.  the full error:

```
NoMethodError in CategoriesController#show

undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x1034703e8>
RAILS_ROOT: /Users/tjs/Sites/emeraldcg

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1998:in `method_missing'
/Users/tjs/Sites/emeraldcg/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:28:in `show'
/Users/tjs/Sites/emeraldcg/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:25:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"acoustic-guitars"}
Show session dump

Response

Headers:

{"Content-Type"=>"text/html",
 "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}
```

my gemfile is pretty straight forward:

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
gem "rails", '2.3.11'
gem "rake"
gem "RedCloth", ">=4.2.2"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 2.3.16"

group :development do
  gem "mysql"
  gem "capistrano"
  gem "capistrano-ext"

end

group :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
end
```

I would understand if this failed due to it being an array but why is it failing as a class method?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past there where some problems with will_paginate and Rails 2, try to update to the latest version op will_paginate. In the meanwhile you can try this :

```
@products = Product.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6,  :conditions => ['brand_id = ? AND category_id = ?', @brand.id, @category.id])
```

Comment: Steenhouwer, thanks for the notes.  That what I thought I saw as well.  I have a broken clients site because of this.  I removed the specific will_paginate version and its now using 3.0.2.  passing the .all method seems to convert the Class to an array which still fails.  It fails though as an undefined method of Array instead of a Class.  any other pagination recommendations?

Comment: I wound up checking out an old git commit and grabbing the old will_paginate plugin... the bundler piece would not work.  Referencing  the will_paginate wiki troubleshooting, Mislav notes that there are two console commands you can run.  Turns out that will_paginate wasn't even loading...  I will post something on on the will_paginate wiki about it.

Comment: @TJSherrill what specfic will_paginate plugin version did you use? Can you link your post on the wiki as well?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call paginate on a model. It can be called on collections like hashes, array, ActiveRecord.