# rails 2.3 will_paginate 2.3.16 undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x7f0ed5f13138>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, will-paginate

I've found a lot of links regarding this problem googling. but nevertheless I still get this error after implementing those fixes.
so my gemfile

> gem 'will_paginate',  '~> 2.3.16'

environment file

> config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.16'

Controller

```
  def index
     @events = Event.paginate({:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10})
  end
```

View:

```
<% @events.each do |item| %>
...
<% end %>  
...  
<%= will_paginate @events %>
```

I'm using rvm, console commands

```
rvm 1.8.7 do bundle install 
...
rvm use 1.8.7 do bundle exec rake gems:install
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails 2, Will\_paginate, undefined method \`paginate' for #<Class:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280872/rails-2-will-paginate-undefined-method-paginate-for-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
      def index
         @events = Event.all.paginate({:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10})
      end
```

Note: **If u get same error still, then just comment out logic of pagination and insert some records in your database table(model) and then use pagination.**

Comment: paginate is method of a class, `all` return different instances. i think i'll go with endless page

Comment: no, it will return all records from ur Event model only. And if u r not expecting it, then tell me what u r expecting from "Event.paginate"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call paginate on a model. It can be called on collections like hashes, array, ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

It may be just a case of restarting the server after you have installed the gem.